# How to use Doxygen to generate documents for Eigen?

Tags: cmake, eigen, doxygen, eigen3, doxygen-wizard

I've tried on my windows PC and in wsl, but it doesn't work, and I'm using the Doxyfile.in it gives in eigen-3.4.0\doc

> error: tag HTML_HEADER: header file '${Eigen_BINARY_DIR}/doc/eigendoxy_header.html' does not exist

It seems that it can't understand the Eigen_BINARY_DIR or something like that. Does it related to my OS? Do I need to try it in macOS?

---

I know where I'm wrong, I didn't process the file before using Doxygen, so I was confused by the difference between Doxyfile and Doxyfile.in and think it may related to my OS.

I tried to use CMake but there is still a problem...

I went to Eigen website and try to learn how to use CMake, I try `cmake .` in WSL(in eigen-3.4.0/doc) but it reports an error, which said:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (check_cxx_compiler_flag):
  Unknown CMake command "check_cxx_compiler_flag".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/c/eigen-3.4.0/doc/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: The Doxyfile.in needs to be processed by cmake first (not sure how this is best done on Windows, but there should be many how-tos for that). Afterwards you should have a `doc` target, which also generates the outputs for all the code-snippets.

Comment: Which version of doxygen a re you using? You should be a bit more specific about your Doxyfile.in and the resulting Doxyfile. Best is to run over **both** : `doxygen -x_noenv` i.e. `doxygen -x_noenv Doxyfile.in` and ``doxygen -x_noenv Doxyfile` and place the results in the question. Note that doxygen uses round brackets (from the documentation https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html: Environment variables can be expanded using the pattern $(ENV_VARIABLE_NAME).)

Comment: Thanks! I know where I'm wrong, I didn't process the file before using Doxygen, so I was confused by the difference between Doxyfile and Doxyfile.in and think it may related to my OS.  This is my first time using StackOverFlow to ask questions, I'm very grateful that you can ask my question!